# Being able to reuse same CancellationTokenSource - CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource

Tags: c#, .net-core, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

I'm trying to figure out what `CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource` actually does. I know it's a regular cancellation source that is also "linked" to an existing token.

The following snippet does the following:

- prints a message > cancels the task -> starts the task again -> prints a message -> cancels the task again and so on.

It's actually reusing same `cts` instance over and over again. Is that behavior coming from `CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource`? I mean when a CancellationTokenSource is canceled, I shouldn't be able to use it again, unless I create a new one instead.

If that's the case, why does the snippet pass a `CancellationToken` to the Start method, when we never actually cancel the `cts`, but the linked one?

```cs
// Program.cs
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

await foreach (var item in items.Start(cts.Token))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
    item.Stop();
    item.Start(cts.Token);
}
```

```cs
private CancellationTokenSource? _cts;

public IAsyncEnumerable<string> Start(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    _cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken);

    ...
}

public void Stop()
{
    _cts?.Cancel();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once `Cancel()` is issued and you want to reuse the CancellationTokenSource perform a check via `IsCancellationRequested`, if true than Dispose _cts and recreate _cts.

```
if (_cts.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    _cts.Dispose();
    _cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken);
}
```

Comment: I know that but I'm asking about `CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource`. 1) I wonder why it lets me reuse same `cts` instance without having to create a new CancellationToken over and over again, even tho I cancel the linked one in that foreach by calling the Stop method (because of the `CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource`?) 2) If it's because of that, why do I even need to pass a CancellationToken in Start method's parameters. I mean I believe I initially took that code from SignalR's implementation. And `cts` is never actually canceled.

Comment: @nop  `CreateLinkedTokenSource` lets you combine multiple cancellation tokens into a new cancellation token source, which itself can also be cancelled. It basically subscribes to the other tokens and cancels itself if one of them is cancelled.

Comment: @nop "I wonder why it lets me reuse same cts instance without having to create a new CancellationToken over and over again" the reason is because in your example, the parent CancellationToken is, as you said, never cancelled. Only the one represented by _cts is.

Comment: I realized that `CreateLinkedTokenSource` is creating a new instance over and over again.